# Android java Messaging problem in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I'm building a multi-user messaging app. I have completed the server setup, but I am having a problem in the user (app) part.

client.java , part of code that create exception

```
public class Client {
public String photo;
public String clientPhoto;
public String clientId;
public PublicKey publicKey;
public PrivateKey privateKey;

public volatile Socket ClientSocket;
public InputStream in;
private  ClientDatabase db;
private Encryption E;



private String ipv4 ;
private int port;



/**
 *   Consturactor need server ipv4 address and port to conndect it
 */
public Client(String ipv4,int port) throws IOException {
    this.ipv4 = ipv4;
    this.port = port;



}


/**
 *  Start recieving message form server
 *
 * */
public void startClient()  {
    
    try {
        ClientSocket= new Socket(ipv4,5551);
        ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(ClientSocket.getInputStream(),db,privateKey);
        clientThread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}





public ClientDatabase createDatabaseOnesTime(@Nullable  Context context){
    db = new ClientDatabase(context);
    return db;
}

/**
 *   This function create key pair (public and private) every client needs to
 *   create their own key pair and they will store private key and publich publickey
 *
 *   When I client want to send message to our client it should ecrypt message with our public key
 *   So ve can read data with our private key
 *
 *   this funcion will start just ones time at installation of app
 *
 **/
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void createPublicPrivateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, SQLException {
    E = new Encryption();
    E.generateKeyPair();
    this.privateKey = E.getPrivate();
    this.publicKey = E.getPublic();
    this.db.addRootAuthTokens(this.E.encodeBase64FromPublicKey(publicKey),this.E.encodeBase64FromPrivateKey(privateKey));

}
```

And MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText edtPhoneNumber ;
private Button btnSignUp;
public static ClientDatabase database ;
public static  Client client ;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    edtPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.edtPhoneNum);
    btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);


    client = null; // Client
    try {
        client = new Client("18.193.114.51", 5551);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client.startClient();


    database = client.createDatabaseOnesTime(MainActivity.this);  // database
```

The ClientThread Class

```
class ClientThread extends Thread{

 private InputStream in;
 private ClientDatabase db;
 private Encryption E;
 private PrivateKey privateKey;

 byte[] data;
 String message;

 public ClientThread(InputStream in, ClientDatabase db,PrivateKey privateKey){
     this.privateKey = privateKey;
     this.db = db;
     this.in = in;

 }


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void run(){
    /**
     * Read everytime message and send message to message processor
     *
     *
     **/




    while (true){
        try {
            if (in.available()!= 0){
                in.read(data);
                message = new String(data);
                messageProccessor(message);
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

I receive all incoming messages with the ClientThread class inside the Client class and process the messages. And by using some functions in the client class, I use the activities that the user is likely to do.
The problem is:
Main activity fails when connecting to Socket server

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ceng201_project, PID: 5412
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ceng201_project/com.example.ceng201_project.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:355)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:565)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:445)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:217)
    at com.example.ceng201_project.Client.startClient(Client.java:66)
    at com.example.ceng201_project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

When I try to make the Socket connection in the ClientThread Class, I cannot get the connected Socket Object from the Thread class and I cannot run other methods that should work. For example, I cannot send messages to the server.

how can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with the network, you have to do your process outside of the main thread.

Previously there was [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) for working with background threads but Asynctask deprecated in API level 30.

You can use [kotlin coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) or [concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) in java

Comment: 'class Invoker implements Executor {
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        r.run();}
}'  I add this to Client.java and update startClient to this '    public void startClient()  {
        Invoker executor = new Invoker();
        executor.execute(()->{
            try {
                ClientSocket= new Socket(ipv4,5551);
                ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(ClientSocket.getInputStream(),db,privateKey);
                clientThread.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}});
    }'

Comment: But the same error "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException   at com.example.ceng201_project.Invoker.execute(Client.java:31)
        at com.example.ceng201_project.Client.startClient(Client.java:73)
        at com.example.ceng201_project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)"

Comment: as I said you should work with the network in the background thread, not on the main thread, do some research about threads and kotlin coroutines

Comment: Thank you but my problem is I am creating Thread and I want to start it in main, Same problem. The tread start main but work  in the background . Where can I start my thread?

Comment: @MIOx08 Can you add your updated code to the question?